# XML para Colunas do Banco de Dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Tenho uma tabela que guarda um XML em uma de suas colunas, porém preciso fazer um select colocando cada item do XML em uma coluna. O problema é que não quero criar mais uma tabela, eu quero algo, nem que seja temporário, só pra ficar mais fácil o acesso aos dados.

Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Viagem xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Identificador>111111</Identificador>
   <EstimativaInicio>2015-09-07T23:46:48</EstimativaInicio>
   <EstimativaFim>2015-09-07T23:46:48</EstimativaFim>
   <IdCliente>000</IdCliente>
   <IdEmbarcador>000</IdEmbarcador>
   <IdUnidade xsi:nil="true" />
   <CNPJUnidade>00000000/0000-00</CNPJUnidade>
   <IdCooperativa xsi:nil="true" />
   <IdTransportadora xsi:nil="true" />
   <TemperaturaMinima>0</TemperaturaMinima>
   <TemperaturaMaxima>0</TemperaturaMaxima>
   <Motorista>JOAO DA SILVA</Motorista>
   <Placa>ITO-7457</Placa>
   <FoneMotorista>0000000000</FoneMotorista>
   <Tipo>AAA</Tipo>
   <Peso>0</Peso>
   <Valor>0</Valor>
   <Cubagem>0</Cubagem>
   <ViagemPrioritaria>1</ViagemPrioritaria>
   <Entregas>
       <Entrega>
           <Sequencia>2</Sequencia>
           <Codigo>000000000/0000-00</Codigo>
           <Referencia>AA COMERCIAL DE ALIMENTOS LTDA</Referencia>
           <Latitude>-00.0000</Latitude>
           <Longitude>-00.0000</Longitude>
           <EstimativaInicio>2015-09-07T00:00:00</EstimativaInicio>
           <EstimativaFim>2015-09-07T10:06:00</EstimativaFim>
           <Peso>28.06</Peso>
           <Cubagem>0</Cubagem>
           <Valor>201.34</Valor>
           <Endereco>RUA, 000</Endereco>
           <Bairro>CENTRO</Bairro>
           <Cidade>CIDADE</Cidade>
       </Entrega>
   </Entregas>
</Viagem>
```

Esse XML acima deverá me retornar uma tabela com as seguintes colunas:

- Identificador;
- EstimativaInicio;
- EstimativaFim;
- IdCliente;
- IdEmbarcador;
- CNPJUnidade;
- TemperaturaMinima;
- TemperaturaMaxima;
- Motorista;
- Placa;
- FoneMotorista;
- Tipo;
- Peso;
- Valor;
- Cubagem; e
- ViagemPrioritaria.

As colunas da tag de Entregas deve ser ignorada pois não será utilizada neste primeiro momento.

Alguém sabe como fazer isto?

Comment: Qual a tecnologia do banco?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Trabalho com SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fins de testes, coloque seu XML dentro de uma variável para testar. Repare que editei os *namespaces* pra funcionar:

```
declare @data xml = '<Viagem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <Identificador>111111</Identificador>
       <EstimativaInicio>2015-09-07T23:46:48</EstimativaInicio>
       <EstimativaFim>2015-09-07T23:46:48</EstimativaFim>
       <IdCliente>000</IdCliente>
       <IdEmbarcador>000</IdEmbarcador>
       <IdUnidade xsi:nil="true" />
       <CNPJUnidade>00000000/0000-00</CNPJUnidade>
       <IdCooperativa xsi:nil="true" />
       <IdTransportadora xsi:nil="true" />
       <TemperaturaMinima>0</TemperaturaMinima>
       <TemperaturaMaxima>0</TemperaturaMaxima>
       <Motorista>JOAO DA SILVA</Motorista>
       <Placa>ITO-7457</Placa>
       <FoneMotorista>0000000000</FoneMotorista>
       <Tipo>AAA</Tipo>
       <Peso>0</Peso>
       <Valor>0</Valor>
       <Cubagem>0</Cubagem>
       <ViagemPrioritaria>1</ViagemPrioritaria>
       <Entregas>
           <Entrega>
               <Sequencia>2</Sequencia>
               <Codigo>000000000/0000-00</Codigo>
               <Referencia>AA COMERCIAL DE ALIMENTOS LTDA</Referencia>
               <Latitude>-00.0000</Latitude>
               <Longitude>-00.0000</Longitude>
               <EstimativaInicio>2015-09-07T00:00:00</EstimativaInicio>
               <EstimativaFim>2015-09-07T10:06:00</EstimativaFim>
               <Peso>28.06</Peso>
               <Cubagem>0</Cubagem>
               <Valor>201.34</Valor>
               <Endereco>RUA, 000</Endereco>
               <Bairro>CENTRO</Bairro>
               <Cidade>CIDADE</Cidade>
           </Entrega>
       </Entregas>
    </Viagem>';

select @data.value('(/Viagem/Identificador/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Identificador, 
    @data.value('(/Viagem/EstimativaInicio/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as EstimativaInicio,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/EstimativaFim/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as EstimativaFim,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/IdCliente/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as IdCliente,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/IdEmbarcador/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as IdEmbarcador,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/CNPJUnidade/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as CNPJUnidade,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/TemperaturaMinima/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as TemperaturaMinima,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/TemperaturaMaxima/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as TemperaturaMaxima,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/Motorista/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Motorista,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/Placa/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Placa,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/FoneMotorista/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as FoneMotorista,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/Tipo/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Tipo,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/Peso/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Peso,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/Valor/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Valor,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/Cubagem/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Cubagem,
    @data.value('(/Viagem/ViagemPrioritaria/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ViagemPrioritaria;
```

Comment: A execução do código que você postou retorna o seguinte erro:

"Msg 9459, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
XML parsing: line 1, character 106, undeclared prefix"

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada!