# XML para registros de tabela temporária

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Semana passada eu [Perguntei Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91438/xml-para-colunas-do-banco-de-dados/91453) sobre como colocar cada tag do XML em uma coluna do banco de dados. Agora me deparei com uma situação próxima disso mas com um plus, meu XML vem do banco de dados, e por vezes não irá vir apenas 1 registro, mas mais de um.

No código a seguir o retorno do sql que está sendo setado para a variável `@xml` retorna 60 registros, ou seja 60 XMLs diferentes.

Como faço pra colocar cada XML em um Registro da minha `@TabelaTemporaria`?

```
DECLARE @DataIni DATETIME = '2015-09-07 23:00:00',
    @DataFim DATETIME = '2015-09-07 23:59:59',
    @xml XML;
DECLARE @TabelaTemporaria TABLE (Identificador VARCHAR(MAX), EstimativaInicio VARCHAR(MAX), EstimativaFim VARCHAR(MAX), IdCliente VARCHAR(MAX), IdEmbarcador VARCHAR(MAX),
                    CNPJUnidade VARCHAR(MAX), TemperaturaMinima VARCHAR(MAX), TemperaturaMaxima VARCHAR(MAX), Motorista VARCHAR(MAX), Placa VARCHAR(MAX),
                    FoneMotorista VARCHAR(MAX), Tipo VARCHAR(MAX), Peso VARCHAR(MAX), Valor VARCHAR(MAX), Cubagem VARCHAR(MAX), ViagemPrioritaria VARCHAR(MAX), Id INT, 
                    TripId INT, CreateDateTime DATETIME);           
SET @xml = ( SELECT RIGHT(TripXML, LEN(TripXML)-CHARINDEX('?>', TripXML)-1) 
            FROM AuditDB.dbo.TripsXML (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE (CreateDateTime BETWEEN @DataIni AND @DataFim) 
        )   
INSERT INTO @TabelaTemporaria (Identificador, EstimativaInicio, EstimativaFim, IdCliente, IdEmbarcador, CNPJUnidade, TemperaturaMinima, TemperaturaMaxima,
                            Motorista, Placa, FoneMotorista, Tipo, Peso, Valor, Cubagem, ViagemPrioritaria, Id, TripId, CreateDateTime)     
SELECT  @xml.value('(/Viagem/Identificador/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Identificador,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/EstimativaInicio/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS EstimativaInicio,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/EstimativaFim/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS EstimativaFim,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/IdCliente/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS IdCliente,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/IdEmbarcador/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS IdEmbarcador,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/CNPJUnidade/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS CNPJUnidade,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/TemperaturaMinima/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TemperaturaMinima,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/TemperaturaMaxima/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TemperaturaMaxima,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/Motorista/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Motorista,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/Placa/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Placa,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/FoneMotorista/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS FoneMotorista,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/Tipo/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Tipo,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/Peso/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Peso,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/Valor/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Valor,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/Cubagem/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Cubagem,
    @xml.value('(/Viagem/ViagemPrioritaria/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ViagemPrioritaria,
    Id,
    TripId,
    CreateDateTime
FROM AuditDB.dbo.TripsXML (NOLOCK) 
WHERE (CreateDateTime BETWEEN @DataIni AND @DataFim)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que não muda muita coisa. A diferença é que você não vai colocar o valor na variável, e vai precisar fazer um *cast* na coluna da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @DataIni DATETIME = '2015-09-07 23:00:00',
    @DataFim DATETIME = '2015-09-07 23:59:59';

DECLARE @TabelaTemporaria TABLE (Identificador VARCHAR(MAX), EstimativaInicio VARCHAR(MAX), EstimativaFim VARCHAR(MAX), IdCliente VARCHAR(MAX), IdEmbarcador VARCHAR(MAX),
                    CNPJUnidade VARCHAR(MAX), TemperaturaMinima VARCHAR(MAX), TemperaturaMaxima VARCHAR(MAX), Motorista VARCHAR(MAX), Placa VARCHAR(MAX),
                    FoneMotorista VARCHAR(MAX), Tipo VARCHAR(MAX), Peso VARCHAR(MAX), Valor VARCHAR(MAX), Cubagem VARCHAR(MAX), ViagemPrioritaria VARCHAR(MAX), Id INT, TripId INT, CreateDateTime DATETIME);           

INSERT INTO @TabelaTemporaria (Identificador, EstimativaInicio, EstimativaFim, IdCliente, IdEmbarcador, CNPJUnidade, TemperaturaMinima, TemperaturaMaxima,
                            Motorista, Placa, FoneMotorista, Tipo, Peso, Valor, Cubagem, ViagemPrioritaria, Id, TripId, CreateDateTime)     
SELECT  
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Identificador/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Identificador,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/EstimativaInicio/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS EstimativaInicio,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/EstimativaFim/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS EstimativaFim,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/IdCliente/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS IdCliente,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/IdEmbarcador/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS IdEmbarcador,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/CNPJUnidade/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS CNPJUnidade,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/TemperaturaMinima/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TemperaturaMinima,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/TemperaturaMaxima/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TemperaturaMaxima,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Motorista/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Motorista,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Placa/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Placa,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/FoneMotorista/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS FoneMotorista,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Tipo/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Tipo,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Peso/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Peso,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Valor/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Valor,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/Cubagem/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Cubagem,
    campoXml.value('(/Viagem/ViagemPrioritaria/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ViagemPrioritaria,
    Id,
    TripId,
    CreateDateTime
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(CAST(RIGHT(TripXML, LEN(TripXML)-CHARINDEX('?>', TripXML)-1)  AS NTEXT) AS XML) as campoXml,
    Id,
    TripId,
    CreateDateTime
    FROM AuditDB.dbo.TripsXML (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE (CreateDateTime BETWEEN @DataIni AND @DataFim)
) Tabela
```

Considere que este *cast* duplo:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(RIGHT(TripXML, LEN(TripXML)-CHARINDEX('?>', TripXML)-1)  AS NTEXT) AS XML) as campoXml
```

Deve acontecer se a sua coluna não for do tipo XML. Se for, não precisa.

Comment: Obrigada... Não sei como não pensei nisso antes!